# Difference of postgreSQL's "trust" and "ident"?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos, postgresql

In postgreSQL's `/var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf` `trust` and `ident` can be set as `method` e.g. like so.

```
# TYPE  DATABASE    USER        CIDR-ADDRESS          METHOD
local   all         postgres                          trust
host    all         postgres    127.0.0.1/32          trust
```

I was under the impression that the difference of the two was with `trust` I as `root` could do

```
psql postgres
```

and with `ident` I had to

```
sudo -u postgres psql postgres
```

However I cannot get the first command to work even with `trust`.

**Question**

Can someone explain what the difference is of `trust` and `ident`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Trust" means "whatever username the client uses, you don't need to ask for a password to verify the user".

"Ident" means "accept whatever the identd returns as the username, without asking for a password to verify".

There's more information about the different authentication methods at [the postgresql site](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html).

In order to figure out why this particular connection failed, you need to check the postgresql logs. It may be that the username you're using doesn't exist in the postgres database, or it may be some other issue - it's impossible to tell without first looking at the logs.

Comment: `ident` is pretty poor, since it requires an `identd` to be running, and that `identd` could answer anything the client computer wants. It's really an awful legacy thing that should be avoided. `peer` for `local` connections remains very useful, though.

Answer (score 7):

`psql` has to connect to a database with a database's username. When it's not specified with the `-U` option, it takes the OS username as a default value.

So in fact, `psql dbname` is equivalent to `psql -U $USER dbname`

As a result, when you're logged as `root` and you haven't created a database user named `root`, this normally yields the following error, even if the authentication mode is `trust`.

> # psql postgres
>     psql: FATAL:  role "root" does not exist

On the other hand, it would work if it was invoked like this, still logged as root:

> # psql -U postgres postgres

which is OK because the database named `postgres` and the user named `postgres` both exist, since they are created automatically during PostgreSQL installation.